# Difficiating objects in a group

Tags: python, object, pygame, sprite

In a group called `powerUpGroup`, there are two objects: `speedUp` and `jumpUP`. The following code checks if the `player` object has collided with any objects in the group:

```
for eachPowerUp in powerUpGroup:        
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(eachPowerUp, playerGroup, False) :
        eachPowerUp.kill()
```

Let's say I **only** want the program to print "Speed increased" when the player collides with `speedUp` object. Based on the code above, it will print the message if it either `speedUp` or `jumpUP` since they are in the same group. Without creating a new group, is there a way for python to **identify** that they are **different** objects  run **certain** code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an if statement to check if the power-up is `speedUp`

```py
for eachPowerUp in powerUpGroup:        
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(eachPowerUp, playerGroup, False):
        if eachPowerUp == speedUp:
            print("Speed increased")
        eachPowerUp.kill()
```

**Edit for second part of question:**
Instead of checking if the power up is a certain object, you can check if it is a certain class.
Say you have a class called `SpeedUp`. You can check to see if `eachPowerUp` is a `SpeedUp` object and then print the message you wanted.

```
for eachPowerUp in powerUpGroup:        
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(eachPowerUp, playerGroup, False):
        if type(eachPowerUp) == SpeedUp:
            print("Speed increased")
        eachPowerUp.kill()
```

Comment: This worked but created another bug. If multiple `speedUp`s(sprite obj) are spawned, touching some registered no collisions. This is because the if statement will only be true if the particular `speedUp` that the player is colliding with is the particular `speedUp` in that variable.

Comment: @DaeshaunMorrison See the edit I made to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If `speedUp` and `jumpUp` are different classes, you should implement their behaviour in their very classes (*something something polymorphism*):

The `speepUp` class should contain the code for speeding up (or whatever it does) and trigger secondary effects (like displaying stuff to the player and removing itself from the game), and the `jumpUp` class should do the same. Of course you could go down the abstraction rabbit hole but let's keep it simple.

Here's a litte example:

```
import pygame
from random import choice

class Actor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, pos, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((64, 64))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        
    def update(self, events, dt):
        pass

class Player(Actor):
    def __init__(self, *grps):
        super().__init__('dodgerblue', (400, 300), *grps)
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.topleft)
        self.dir = pygame.Vector2((0, 0))
        self.speed = 300
        
    def update(self, events, dt):
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.dir.x, self.dir.y = (0, 0)
        if pressed[pygame.K_d]: self.dir += ( 1,  0)
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]: self.dir += (-1,  0)
        if pressed[pygame.K_s]: self.dir += ( 0,  1)
        if pressed[pygame.K_w]: self.dir += ( 0, -1)
        
        if self.dir.length() > 0:
            self.dir.normalize()
        
        self.pos += self.dir * self.speed * dt
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos
        

class PowerUp(Actor):
    def __init__(self, color, pos, player, *grps):
        super().__init__(color, pos, *grps)
        self.player = player

    def apply(self):
        pass

    def update(self, events, dt):
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, self.player):
            self.apply()
            self.kill()

class SpeedUp(PowerUp):
    def __init__(self, player, *grps):
        super().__init__('yellow', (100, 100), player, *grps)
     
    def apply(self):
        print('Speed Up')
        self.player.speed += 200

class ColorChange(PowerUp):
    def __init__(self, player, *grps):
        super().__init__('purple', (600, 300), player, *grps)
     
    def apply(self):
        print('ColorChange!')
        self.player.image.fill(choice(['green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'grey']))

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    clock, dt = pygame.time.Clock(), 0
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player(sprites)
    SpeedUp(player, sprites)
    ColorChange(player, sprites)
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events: 
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
        screen.fill('black')
        sprites.draw(screen)
        sprites.update(events, dt)
        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(120)/1000
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: I think I understand the general idea. By giving the objects to the player's params, you can trigger certain actions? If isn't correct, can you please add some comments so I can understand the code better

Comment: Yes, giving certain objects the reference to the player object allows us to easily change attributes or call methods on that player object. This is of course not the only way to do this; another nice and simple way is to create a class that represents the game context and pass that instead of only the player. That game context then provides methods for all sprites to access the player, global attributes (e.g. a score or the level number etc.) and methods to create another sprites (e.g. a function `display_text` to, well, show some text on the screen).

Comment: I have not added this as the correct answer because I don't know how to apply this to my program. In @AlarmClockMan 's answer I was able to print a different message based on the sprite I collided with. However, there is a bug that if multiple `speedUp` are spawned, only the first collision is registered.

Answer (score 0):

The previous code was an equality test between two sprites, not a type of sprite.  The variable `speedUp` is one of your `powerUpGroup` sprites.  The if statement will only be true if the particular `speedUp` that the player is colliding with is the particular `speedUp` in that variable.

So I added a property.
In the constructor(That was not added in the OP), I have `self.type = "multiShot"` or  `self.type = "speed"`, depending on which type it is.  Then, an if statement would now be something like:

```
for eachPowerUp in powerUpGroup:
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(eachPowerUp, playerGroup, False) :
        if eachPowerUp.type == "multiShot" :
            ...
        elif eachPowerUp.type == "speed" :
            ...
```